# Graph API not returning image/picture for community pages

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api

Graph API is not returning image("picture" attribute) for objects corresponding to community pages, which used to be returned earlier. For example this https://graph.facebook.com/178790412179919 does not have picture attribute whereas the corresponding page has an image.

Also the FQL query done on the "albums" connection for some objects does not have a "cover_pid" attribute for an album corresponding to type "profile", which again used to work earlier.

Does anybody know if anything has changed in Graph API corresponding to this in last couple of weeks (I am fairly confident it used to work earlier in the expected way). I looked through Facebook API release notes but could not find any changes corresponding to this. Please let me know if this not appropriate post for this forum.

Comment: are you trying to get photos from your facebook page?

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/

`picture` is a connection, not an attribute. So ...

https://graph.facebook.com/178790412179919/picture

And as the docs say: `Returns a HTTP 302 with the URL of the user's profile picture.`

Kinda goofy? Yes, but it works exactly as the docs say it does. I suspect they implemented it this way so it could easily be used in an `<IMG>` tag.

Comment: `picture` is mentioned in the fields table in the same doc. it seems something needs to be configured to fetch the picture in response of graph api call.

Comment: Facebook's API changes randomly and often. This post was from almost a year ago which means most certainly the API and docs have changed. I no longer have any interest in Facebook and haven't used their API in some time.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

It still works via FQL. In your case:

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT+page_id%2C+pic+FROM+page+WHERE+page_id+%3D+178790412179919&format=json

---

I can confirm that this PREVIOUSLY worked, but NO LONGER works. Facebook have removed the picture connection from Community Pages.

I suspect the reason is that most of these images are pulled from Wikipedia, and there was a licensing / attribution issue.

Unfortunately, Facebook is no longer a reliable source of images for entities (e.g. bands).